# Are there any yellow ferrous (ideally stainless) alloys? Perhaps after heating?

Tags: materials, color, metallurgy

I recently learned about purple gold, which is roughly 80%-20% Au - Al by weight. (It's beautiful.) I also know that Titanium will turn bright purple if heated sufficiently (probably an oxide layer). The 300 series stainless will also turn into various colors after welding. I am curious if there are any stainless steels (ideally) or other ferrous alloys that are YELLOW, (and if by a heat-induced coating, a uniform yellow).

Comment: Perhaps titanium nitride coated steel? Commonly used for drill bits: https://homesteady.com/12504204/what-are-titanium-drills-used-for, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium_nitride